# При вводе символов, перепутаны значения клавиш ubuntu 16.04

Tags: ubuntu, locale, клавиатура

Первый раз в жизни сталкиваюсь с подобным, на сервере ubuntu 16.04 server, когда подключаешь клавиатуру, вместо например латинской буквы O, когда на неё нажимаешь, вводится буква R, вместо D , E и так вся клавиатура будто сдвинута направо. Все кнопки перепутаны, как будто кто-то налету подменяет коды клавиш , я даже не могу пароль ввести нормально.
На системе стоит американская локаль. 
Пробывал с другой клавиатурой - тоже самое.

Когда подключаешься по ssh , все правильно вводится.

Что это за чудеса?

Comment: Скорей всего кто-то решил научиться печатать на [Двораке](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%83%D1%80%D0%B0_%D0%94%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%B0)

Comment: @Fat-Zer , вот да у меня иммено такая раскладка сейчас, как её поменять на человеческую qwerty ? С меня хватит , я уже научился, больше не хочу =)

Comment: если в бубунтах клава настраивается как в дебиане, то скорей всего надо будет подправить `/etc/default/keyboard`, а именно в `XKBVARIANT` убрать вариант соответствующий американской раскладке... пусть название не смущает — оно должно применяться как к иксам, так и к консоли...

Comment: @Fat-Zer помогло спасибо, действительно стоял Дворак.

Answer (score 1):

Также помогло сменить Language в разделе Language and Region в настройках с English (United States) на English (United Kingdom)